# Widgets drawing in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, paintevent

I have been looking all over the Internet and I don't find any solution to my problem so I have a bar like this:

[image: Scroll bar with pictures for handlers]

(Scroll bar with pictures for handlers)

But when I scroll the pictures through the other what happen is:

[image]

Is there anyway to stop over painting the sad face over the happy one?

This is the `paintEvent` method

```
void QSlider::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    if (ori_==Qt::Horizontal)
    {

        if(index>=0)
        {
            this->setFixedSize(42,57);
            printf("\n");
            QString dir="C:\\Qt\\Qt5.2.1\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\pluginss\\";
            QString emo=QString::fromStdString(emotions.at(index));
            dir.append(emo);
            dir.append(".png");
            QPixmap pixmap(dir);
            painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0), pixmap.scaled(40,40, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
            QRect rec(0,22,40,40);
            painter.drawText(rec,Qt::AlignCenter,emo);
        }
        else 
        {
            this->setFixedSize(10,20);
            QRect rec(0,7,8,8);
            painter.drawRect(rec);
            QPolygon pp;
            pp << QPoint(0,7) << QPoint(4,0) << QPoint(8,7);
            painter.drawPolygon(pp, Qt::OddEvenFill);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my `mouseMoveEvent`:

```
void QSliderWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if (activeSlider_>=0)
    {
        QRect crec = contentsRect();
        qreal pos;
        crec.adjust(rampeditor_->bspace_,0,-rampeditor_->bspace_,0);
        pos = 1.0*(e->pos().x()-rampeditor_->bspace_)/(crec.width());

        if (pos<0.0 || pos>1.0)
        {
            delete(rampeditor_->sliders_[activeSlider_]);
            rampeditor_->sliders_.removeAt(activeSlider_);
            activeSlider_ = -1;
            rampeditor_->updateRamp();
        }
        else
        {
            rampeditor_->sliders_[activeSlider_]->move(0,e->pos().y());
            seconds.replace(activeSlider_-1,e->pos().x());
            qSort(rampeditor_->sliders_.begin(), rampeditor_->sliders_.end(), QColorRampEditor::SliderSort);
            index=activeSlider_-1;
            rampeditor_->mergeSort(0,seconds.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you code share your code for the above.

Comment: Done sorry :) and Thank you

Comment: What would you think the result should look like? If you draw a graphic partly above another graphic, the lower (earlier drawn) will be overlapped. --> We cannot draw 7 perfectly perpendicular lines in red, green and transparent using red ink.

Comment: Well of course thats why I need help with this, I am new in QT and i would like to know if there's anyway of not repainting if intercepts a pixmap